# What is the difference between Google Authenticator TOTP and regular TOTP

Tags: one-time-password, google-authenticator

Google Authenticator app produces tokens which we try to reproduce with an OTP library ([otplib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/otplib)) as follows. Even when run at the same time, one matches and the other doesn't

```
import { authenticator, totp, hotp } from 'otplib'

const secret = "NZQKPMNENSPOWUQZ"

console.log(authenticator.generate(secret)) // matches the app token
console.log(totp.generate(secret)) // does not match
```

Why do the two generated tokens differ? One difference between the options for each generator is the encoding so also tried this with same results

```
totp.options = {encoding: 'hex'} // default is 'ascii'
```

How to generate the same code with `totp` (or `hotp`) as with `authenticator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question as you and I figured out why these objects generate different values.

The value `NZQKPMNENSPOWUQZ` is a base32 encoded string. So you have decode it, convert it to hex, then set the encoding to `hex` on the `totp` object, and you're good. The `authenticator` object does all that for you. The `totp` object does not.

```js
import { authenticator, totp, hotp } from 'otplib';
import { KeyEncodings } from 'otplib/core';
import base32Decode from 'base32-decode'; // for ease of use

const secret = 'NZQKPMNENSPOWUQZ'; // this is base32 encoded

console.log(authenticator.generate(secret));

// decode base32 key to hex string
const hexSecret = Buffer.from(base32Decode(secret, 'RFC4648')).toString('hex');

// set totp option encoding to 'hex'
totp.options = { encoding: KeyEncodings.HEX };

// pass in the decoded hex secret
console.log(totp.generate(hexSecret));

// BONUS
// generate the code with hotp
// all three use hotp under the hood
// generate the counter correctly and now you have totp
hotp.options = { encoding: KeyEncodings.HEX };
const step = 30; // seconds per code
const counter = Math.floor(Date.now() / step / 1000);
console.log(hotp.generate(hexSecret, counter));
```

[Source: This is where I found the `authenticator` object automatically decodes the base32 secret](https://github.com/yeojz/otplib/blob/147e67637377196e3c59cf93b12ac325aca76fac/packages/otplib-core/src/authenticator.ts#L191)

Comment: ah so just had to hex the secret. abandoned this project but great find!